# Delete carriage return in powershell

Tags: file, powershell, return

I having troubles deleting carriage return within a text file. I want to delete carriage return just for "Message". I need the "Message" content to be on just one line.

My input looks like:

```
TimeCreated      : 08/04/2014 22:31:15
LevelDisplayName : Information
Id               : 50065
Message          : DHCP a trouvé dans le cache une corespondance pour l’identificateur                  
                  (Service Set Identifier) Livebox-816F (valeur hexadécimale de 
                   l’identificateur SSID : C496674) pour la carte réseau dont l’adresse 
                   réseau est 0x0C
```

I came up with this line of code but it doesn't work:

```
$MyObject = Get-WinEvent -LogName 'Microsoft-Windows-Dhcp-Client/Admin' | Where-Object {$_.TimeCreated -ge $lastsevendays} | Select 'TimeCreated', 'LevelDisplayName', 'ID', @{n='Message';e={$_.Message -replace '`r', " "}}, $Size 
$MyObject > $SourceFile
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try using `'backtick n'` instead of `'backtick r'` in your `-replace`.

Comment: It stills doesn't work...

Comment: What happens when you try?  It seems to work for me, though I removed `$Size` from the end of your command, since it's undefined.

Comment: OP is not (just) trying to remove line breaks from `Message`, they are trying to remove line breaks from the *powershell list-formatted output* of the resulting object.  This is trickier, you will either have to log with standard formatting then rewrite the log, or use custom output formatting.

Comment: I guess for fun you could export the output to a text file, read the text file as binary data, convert that to hex and remove any hexadecimal instances of `0D 0A` (which is the carriage return/line feed in hex).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (folded at the pipes for readability):

```
$MyObject = Get-WinEvent -LogName 'Microsoft-Windows-Dhcp-Client/Admin' |
 Where-Object {$_.TimeCreated -ge $lastsevendays} |
  Select 'TimeCreated', 'LevelDisplayName', 'ID', @{n='Message';e={$_.Message -replace '\r', " "}} 

$MyObject > $SourceFile
```

The escape character in the Powershell parser is the backtick, but those rules don't apply within the regex argument for -Replace.  There you have to use regex parsing rules, and a carriage return  is '\r'

Note: if you want it all as a single line, you'll also have to replace the newline, so your replace would be '\r\n',''

Answer (score 0):

Arg, SO timed out on me and killed my answer. Here, this worked for me. I saved your sample text to a file C:\Temp\Test.txt. Then I ran this script against it:

```
$Logs = GC C:\Temp\test.txt
$Event = New-Object PSObject
for($i=0;$i -lt $logs.count;$i++){
    If($Logs[$i] -match "^\S"){
        $Current = $logs[$i].split(":")
        Add-Member -InputObject $Event -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $Current[0].TrimEnd(" ") -Value $Current[1].TrimStart(" ")
        $last = $current[0].TrimEnd(" ")}
    else
    {$Event.$last = $event.$last+$logs[$i].TrimStart(" ")}
}
```

That leaves me with $Event which is an object that has 4 properties:

- TimeCreated
- LevelDisplayName
- Id
- Message

Where $Event.Message is a single string as you desired in your request.

**Edit:** Seeing that you are outputting events, it looks like you're having wrapping issues due to width constraints. Instead of `$MyObject > $SourceFile` do this:

```
$MyObject|fl|Out-File test1.txt -Width $($($MyEvent.Message.Length)+20)
```

That will output it like what you had except it will have each item on it's own line, and it will format the width to be the length of the Message property + 20 characters to allow for the `Message       :` before it.

Answer (score 0):

Update:

It's not clear whether or not the OP wants to remove CRs only or CRLFs. For "Message content to be on just one line", you need to remove both CRs and LFs.

@latkin makes a good point noting that the OP might be concerned about not only the property values but the formatted PowerShell output.

To remove both CRs and LFs from the actual property values:

```
$MyObject = Get-WinEvent -LogName 'Microsoft-Windows-Dhcp-Client/Admin' | where TimeCreated -GE $lastsevendays | Select TimeCreated, LevelDisplayName, Id, Message | Remove-NewLines | fl

$MyObject > $sourceFile
```

Update 2:

fl (Format-List), however, will wrap the output based on your console width. To prevent that, pipe to Out-String using the max width (then remove only the CRs if that is your intention):

```
$MyObject = Get-WinEvent -LogName 'Microsoft-Windows-Dhcp-Client/Admin' | where TimeCreated -GE $lastsevendays | Select TimeCreated, LevelDisplayName, Id, Message | Remove-NewLines | fl | Out-String -Width 2147483647 | Remove-NewLines -CR

$MyObject > $sourceFile
```

Using this general-purpose filter:

```
filter Remove-NewLines([string[]]$Name = '*', [switch]$CR, [switch]$LF)
{
    $crlf = @{ CR = "`r"; LF = "`n" }
    $newLine = $crlf.Keys | where { $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey($_) } | foreach { $crlf[$_] }

    if (-not $newLine)
    {
        $newLine = "`r", "`n"
    }

    $newLine = $newLine -join '|'

    if ($_ -is [string] -or $_ -is [ValueType])
    {
        return $_ -replace $newLine
    }

    $object = $_ | select *

    $object.psobject.Properties | 
        where IsSettable |
        where {
            $propertyName = $_.Name
            $Name | where { $propertyName -like $_ } | select -First 1
        } |
        foreach { try { $_.Value = $_.Value -replace $newLine } catch { } }

    $object
}
```

Example 1:

```
PS> Get-WinEvent -LogName 'Microsoft-Windows-Dhcp-Client/Admin' | Remove-NewLines

Removes CRs and LFs from all properties.
```

Example 2:

```
PS> Get-WinEvent -LogName 'Microsoft-Windows-Dhcp-Client/Admin' | Remove-NewLines M* -CR

Removes CRs from the Message property.
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably a stupid journeyman answer, but I had a similar problem and something like this worked:

```
$newdelimiter=" "
$f=get-command attach.txt -raw
$f -replace "\r\n",$newdelimiter
```

May have missed the point, apologies if I did.  Works for me to take huge hunks of HTML and do screen scraping on it.

Comment: I would give you a hard time about not following PowerShell community best practices, but when has Minasi ever followed convention? :)

Comment: Darn, I hate when there's some rule I skipped.  What did I do wrong... is there a link somewhere?  I was just trying to help. <wince> :)

Comment: It's not a StackOverflow thing so much as PowerShell best practices. The biggest thing is not using aliases when sharing code, both for readability and portability.

Comment: Sonufagun.  Interesting, it seems that every Get-Content example I see uses "gc."  I can see not creating an alias for myself and using that, but I kind of thought that everyone just uses gcm, gc, gm, ipmo and the like within about five minutes of learning the cmdlet.  But I definitely see why it might be superior as a teaching tool.  Thanks!